# Retrieving aggregates from inside of other aggregates

Tags: python, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have been studying DDD for over year now, but I'm still quite unhappy with my aggregate understanding. I have prepared a complicated use case example in python where some issues with aggregates arises.

Use case: Player can order his unit to attack other unit, he chooses with what power attack will be made. After attack, owner of attacked unit is notified of that fact.

My problem is that when unit attacks another unit in domain logic, I have access to only those unit aggregates, but to compute damage done on attack I need access to aggregates referenced by id on these units. In particular for Weapon and Armor aggregates (which are ARs because they can exist without unit and I would like to track their history).

I have two options:

1. load these aggregate in domain service and pass as arguments in function call:

`unit.attack_other_unit_with_power(unit_being_attacked, power, weapon, armor)`

but it looks really bad.

2. Load weapon and armor aggregates from inside of unit aggregate.

I have prepared code to present that approach.

Application service.

```
"""
Game application services.
"""

from game.domain.model.attackpower import AttackPower
from game.domain.exception import PlayerNotOwnerOfUnit, UnitCannotMeleeAttack


class GameService(object):
    """
    Game application services.
    """
    def __init__(self, player_repository, unit_repository):
        """
        Init.

        :param PlayerRepository player_reposistory: Player repository.
        :param UnitRepository unit_reposistory: Unit repository.
        """
        self._player_repository = player_repository
        self._unit_repository = unit_repository

    def player_order_unit_to_melee_attack_another_unit_using_power(
        self, player_id, unit_id, unit_being_attacked_id, power
    ):
        """
        Player order his unit to melee attack other unit, using given power.

        :param int player_id: Player id.
        :param int unit_id: Player unit id.
        :param int unit_being_attacked_id: Id of unit that is being attacked.
        :param float power: Power percentage value .
        """
        player = self._player_repository.get_by_id(player_id)
        unit = self._unit_repository.get_by_id(unit_id)
        unit_being_attacked = self._unit_repository.get_by_id(unit_being_attacked_id)
        attack_power = AttackPower(power)

        if not self._is_player_owner_of_unit(player, unit):
            raise PlayerNotOwnerOfUnit(player, unit)
        if not unit.can_melee_attack():
            raise UnitCannotMeleeAttack(unit)
        unit.melee_attack_unit_using_power(unit_being_attacked, attack_power)

        self._unit_repository.store(unit)
        self._unit_repository.store(unit_being_attacked)
```

Unit aggregate.

```
from game.domain.model.health import Health
from game.domain.model.event.unitwasattacked import UnitWasAttacked
from game.domain.service.damage import calculate_damage


class Unit(object):
    """
    Unit aggregate.
    """
    def __init__(self, id, owner_id, player_repository, weapon_repository, armor_repository, event_dispatcher):
        """
        Init.

        :param int id: Id of this unit.
        :param int owner_id: Id of player that is owner of this unit.
        :param PlayerRepository player_repository: Player repository implementation.
        :param WeaponRepository weapon_repository: Weapon repository implementation.
        :param ArmorRepository armor_repository: Armor repository implementation.
        :param EventDispatcher event_dispatcher: Event dispatcher.
        """
        self._id = id
        self._owner_id = owner_id
        self._health = Health(100.0)
        self._weapon_id = None
        self._armor_id = None
        self._player_repository = player_repository
        self._weapon_repository = weapon_repository
        self._armor_repository = armor_repository
        self._event_dispatcher = event_dispatcher

    def id(self):
        """
        Get unit id.

        :return: int
        """
        return self._id

    def can_melee_attack(self):
        """
        Check if unit can melee attack.

        :return: bool
        """
        if self._is_fighting_bare_hands():
            return True
        weapon = self._weapon_repository.get_by_id(self._weapon_id)
        if weapon.is_melee():
            return True
        return False

    def _is_fighting_bare_hands(self):
        """
        Check if unit is fighting with bare hands (no weapon).

        :return: bool
        """
        return self.has_weapon()

    def has_weapon(self):
        """
        Check if unit has weapon equipped.

        :return: bool
        """
        if self._weapon_id is None:
            return False
        return True

    def melee_attack_unit_using_power(self, attacked_unit, attack_power):
        """
        Melee attack other unit using given attack power.

        :param Unit attacked_unit: Unit being attacked.
        :param AttackPower attack_power: Attack power.
        """
        weapon = self.weapon()
        armor = attacked_unit.armor()

        damage = calculate_damage(weapon, armor, attack_power)
        attacked_unit.deal_damage(damage)

        self._notify_unit_owner_of_attack(attacked_unit)

    def _notify_unit_owner_of_attack(self, unit):
        """
        Notify owner of given unit that his unit was attacked.

        :param Unit unit: Attacked unit.
        """
        unit_owner = unit.owner()
        unit_was_attacked = UnitWasAttacked(unit.id(), unit_owner.id())
        self._event_dispatcher.dispatch(unit_was_attacked)

    def owner(self):
        """
        Get owner aggregate.

        :return: Player
        """
        return self._player_repository.get_by_id(self._owner_id)

    def armor(self):
        """
        Get armor object.

        :return: Armor
        """
        if self._armor_id is None:
            return None
        return self._armor_repository.get_by_id(self._armor_id)

    def weapon(self):
        """
        Get weapon object.

        :return: Weapon
        """
        if self._weapon_id is None:
            return None
        return self._weapon_repository.get_by_id(self._weapon_id)

    def deal_damage(self, damage):
        """
        Deal given damage to self.

        :param Damage damage: Dealt damage.
        """
        self._health.take_damage(damage)
```

Question is if this is ok to access reposistory from inside of aggregate only for read (no storing)?
What if I would like to take armor of unit and do some changes to it and then store.

`armor = unit.armor()  # loaded using repository internally
armor.repair()
armor_repository.store(armor)`

Is it violating anything or would that cause problems?

If you have any other remarks for this code I would be glad to hear it.

**UPDATE**: I've found another problem. What if I would like to degrade weapon quality after each attack?
I would have to change weapon state and store it, but storing from insisde of aggregate is a bad idea, because we have no control over it.

Comment: Perhaps you could leverage some domain events to handle degrading a weapon.  Create an event such as "WeaponUsedInAttack" that contains some values regarding the weapon and attack, then you could have a handler subscribe to that and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: You have a point, but there should be only one way of doing an attack with weapon in code, so using event is redundant, except that in event handler I can use repository. And here my next question raises:  Why we can use repository in domain service but not in aggregate method? Technically it's the same I'll create separate SO thread for it.

Comment: I think you overlooked the fact that ARs can reference other ARs, as long as only one gets modified per transaction. If one AR needs another to fulfill it's tasks, then you should probably reference the other AR by reference rather than by `id`.

Comment: It can, but Vaughn Vernon discourages to do it. Of course it doesn't have to be right in every case. But that way constructing of aggregate tree would be troublesome if there is long chain of references. Also what if I will modify that referenced aggregate during my task, I can't store it, and also application layer won't know that it has to store it when it's changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is a bad idea to do anything with repositories from within your aggregates.  Especially performing operations on another aggregate's repository from within an unrelated aggregate.  The purpose of an aggregate is to maintain the invariants of that entity, and that entity alone.  Whenever you are performing actions on multiple entities, you probably want that to go in a domain service.

I would say your best option out of the 2, is the first one.  If you truly need many objects to calculate damage, then it may be cleaner to package them in a value object.  You don't necessarily need all the properties of each entity in this new value object, only the ones that apply to damage calculation.  You could call this new object "DamageAttributes" and then your method signature would look like this:

```
unit.attack_other_unit_with_power(unit_being_attacked, damage_attributes)
```

As a final side note, I tried doing a similar DDD game engine a while back for one of my games.  I ran into a lot of friction just like you are, and eventually scrapped it in favor of a more transaction script approach.  My life got a lot easier and I haven't regretted the choice once.  Not all projects are good candidates for DDD, and this may be one of them in my opinion.  DDD shines most when the rules are constantly changing, but with game engines it usually isn't the rules that change so much as the data (hit points, health, armor).  You must ask yourself what you are gaining from DDD.  In my case I couldn't come up with a compelling answer.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Your approach with additional ValueObject is interesting, but I think that this way lot of logic leaks up to an application layer. Like knowledge that weapon and armor aggregates are needed for damage calculation. I came up with another solution - puting attacking logic into domain service, but this way my Unit AR gets anemic. As to Your question about advantages of using DDD. I think that such problems as I have here are coming up in most domains, so if DDD won't work with that, then it won't work for most domains. I'll keep trying with DDD, or at least DDD Lite.

Comment: Nothing would be leaked to the application layer.  The value object exists in the domain layer, and is constructed in the domain layer.  You could pass weapon, power, damage into the value object's constructor and have it set it's internal properties accordingly.  I agree you will end up with an anemic domain model, but in this case it may not be the worst thing.

Comment: I forgot to add, that I'm not using DDD for game engine. Game engine is mostly about infrastructure, not game logic. IMO game engine should be just a client using our application services. I'll mark Your answer as accepted if there will be no more answers that I can take into consideration.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps I used the wrong term when I said game engine.  I think we mean the same thing (backend that everything talks to) :)